# Cache size set,but don't work,rethink with empty tables still consume huge meory in dev machine

Tags: rethinkdb

In my dev machine,rethinkdb is consuming almost 5gb memory.it is big waste,so I add this line "cache-size=512" to "/etc/rethinkdb/instances.d/default.conf",then restart it,but it still consumes almost 5 gb memory,why?

by the way,I have 70 tables,and all empty(some may contains 1~5 records for testing),and configuration is:

```
ubuntu 14.04 64bit  8gb memory
rethinkdb 1.15.2 64bit
```

Comment: Quick note for everyone reading here: We're currently discussing this at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rethinkdb/CiI2wu7bwoI

Answer (score 1):

There was an inefficiency in how RethinkDB handled large metadata on server startup that caused this under certain circumstances.
A fix for this is going to ship with RethinkDB 1.16.

See https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/3463 for details.